Alternate encodings of the same x86 (64) operation
Is there any difference in behavior or performance of these two encodings of the mov r11, rsp operation?
49 89 E3    mov r11, rsp
4C 8B DC    mov r11, rsp

How should I break down these opcodes into their bitfields ?

There is no difference. It's unclear what you mean by "broken down".

AFAIK opcodes break down into different bit-fields and every one of these fields has a different meaning to the CPU.

One is MOV r/m64, r64 the other is the reverse. Since both can encode two register operands it does not matter which one you use.

Got it - so one is mov  r/m64, r64 and the other on is mov  r64, r/m64

49 89 C3 = REX.WB 89 MOD=11 REG=100 RM=011 4C 8B DC = REX.WR 8B MOD=11 REG=011 RM=100 (notice REG and RM are swapped along with the REX bits) Also the opcode has a direction bit #1 which is toggled.

Related: Why does the Solaris assembler generate different machine code than the GNU assembler here?.

Please write me more about the direction bit.

It just signals which operand is the source and which is the destination. With the bit clear you have r/m64, r64 with the bit set you have r64, r/m64.

And that direction bit is the 2nd youngest bit in the opcode byte -  89 vs. 8B ?

Yes that is correct. It is also present in some other opcodes.
